# How do I get out of the rocks around the chest in the maze?

Tags: vim-adventures

I can get to where the chest is at the beginning, surrounded by rocks, but I can't get back out. I need capital W, I think. Could somebody tell me where to get it?

Answer (score 5):

press capital "B"
so you  will jump to WORDS

Answer (score 4):

I got stuck on this as well, you need to use the `e` key, but you don't have this at the start of the level, you need to continue along the island and jump across to the `e` key so you can use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the <kbd>e</kbd> key while on the `S` square (lower right corner)

> Forward to the end of word [count].
>
> Position the cursor at the end of the word.
>
> Does not stop in an empty line.
>
> A word (see `:help word`) consists of a sequence of letters, digits and
>   underscores, or a sequence of other non-blank characters, separated
>   with white space (spaces, tabs, EOL). An empty line is also considered
>   to be a word.